# Difference in features between CRF++ and SimpleTagger in Mallet

Tags: mallet, crf++

I'm doing some experiments to compare time performance between CRF++ and SimpleTagger in Mallet. However, after running, I see there is a gap difference in accuracy between them, although I set same parameter (L2-norm). I try to figure it out by printing out the feature created from CRF++ and Mallet but I can't do that with Mallet.
So, is there any difference between features of CRF++ and Mallet? How can I print out the features created by Mallet?